# Add Chosen in Wordpress frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Good morning.

I would like to add Chosen style in Wordpress Frontend Select.
I've enqueue CSS and JS in a specific page:

```
function enqueue_chosen() {
  if ( is_page( 'my-page' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'chosen_css', plugins_url('chosen/chosen.css') );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'chosen_js', plugins_url('chosen/chosen.jquery.js'), array('jquery'), '', true );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_chosen' );
```

File is enqueued correctly. Now how I can apply chosen style in my select box?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_' );` is not complete because your function is called `enqueue_chosen` and you've written in you action just `enqueue_` change it like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_chosen' );
```

Next, to use the styles of the `chosen_css` you could go to the wordpress theme customizer and edit the css in the section `Additional CSS`:
[image]

You can write your css there and it will be applied to all your wordpress pages.

Comment: Thanks I've fixed answer code. My problem is that select not use chosen. It is a plain select.

Comment: Before changing the css, what you want to do is add `chosen` specific classes like `.chosen-choices` in your html to the elements that you want to style with this framework. Basically chosed lets you transform your select box using jquery. So first add a class to your select box like `class="my-select-box"` and with a plugin like custom css and js: https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/ you can write the javascript `$(".my-select-box").chosen()` take a look at the options available here https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html

Answer (score 2):

Below are three steps to turn any select box in your Wordpress page into a Chosen type select box.

1. enqueue the chosen library in your themes functions.php

---

```
function my_enqueue_files() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'chosen_styles', 'https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css', false );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'chosen_js', 'https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_files' );
```

2. put the `jQuery(document).ready(function...)` in one script at the bottom of the page and then another script calling the `jQuery(document).ready(function...)`.
   Note: This must be in two scripts.
   the snippet:

---

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery(".chosen-select").chosen({
          search_contains: true,
          no_results_text: "Nothing found for: ",
          width: "100%",
      });
    });
    $('select').chosen({

    allow_single_deselect: true
    });
    </script>`
    `<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".chosen").chosen();
    });
    </script>
```

3. Use the `class='chosen'` on the particular select.

for select with one selection:

---

```
`<select class="chosen" style="width:200px;">
    <option>Choose...</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
        .....
```

for select with multiple selections:

```
<select class="chosen" multiple="true" style="width:400px;">
    <option>Choose...</option>
       ....
```

Hope it helps.